# this["instancename"] syntax

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I see my co-workers use this horrid syntax a lot:

```
var mc1: MovieClip;
var mc2: MovieClip;
var mc3: MovieClip;
var mc4: MovieClip;
var mc5: MovieClip;

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
   addChild(this["mc" + i]); // UURRGGHHH
   TweenLite.to(this["mc"+i], 1, {alpha: 0}); // FNNNGGGGGHHHH
}
```

Because I'm a bossy sod, I'm putting together a list of reasons why they should use arrays for iteration, not nasty square-bracket syntax. I know it's wrong to use that syntax but I can't think of enough compelling reasons why they should abandon it.

Hit me with some facts, please.

Comment: Yep, I agree. Legibility too.

Comment: +1 for raising a question about a pet hate :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Using an array makes it easy to add another item. You don't have to declare a new variable.
- You don't have to modify the limit of your `for` loop when you add another item.
- You only have one variable to rename if that need arises.
- It helps you think in a fruitful manner when you can recognize a collection of things by a semantically useful definition.

Answer (score 6):

Type-safety.

The square-bracket syntax will not result in the a decent type so that the compiler can check for problems at compile time.  I show no mercy to people who come to me with runtime exceptions caused by type problems.

Seriously, the type system in AS3 is there for a reason.  Use it.  Don't figure out ways to work around it.  It prevents problems.

Answer (score 4):

I'll argue with you here, and say that you shouldn't be using arrays, but **vectors**.

Comment: I've never touched vectors due being on CS3 for so long. Now I'm using CS5, I'll have a look at them. +1 for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: vectors are better because you have added type safety, and because of that iterating is a lot faster too.

Answer (score 0):

A fact : I just use a similar way this afternoon.

But, below way may meet 'their' expection:

> var mcs:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3, mc4, mc5];
>
> for (var i:int = 1; i <= mcs.length; i++)
>   {
>      addChild(mcs[i]);
>      TweenLite.to(mcs[i], 1, {alpha: 0});
>   }